# aws opsworks cli run cookbook and capture cookbook output

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I am trying to execute a recipe via AWS opsworks cli it is working without any problem. The problem is it is returning "DeploymentId" as output. I am executing the following command-

```
aws opsworks create-deployment --stack-id c7cxxxxx-efxx-xxxx-xxxx-1dexxxxxxc78 --command {"Name":"execute_recipes", "Args":{"recipes":["cookbook::recipes"]}}
```

Output-

> {
>       "DeploymentId": "824749ec-7e20-42ca-89c5-6646cf0c863c"
>   }

I want to get the opsworks instances chef deployment output - like -

```
[2017-03-14T00:06:50-04:00] INFO: Starting chef-zero on port 8889 with repository at repository at /opt/aws/opsworks/current
One version per cookbook
data_bags at /var/lib/aws/opsworks/data/data_bags
nodes at /var/lib/aws/opsworks/data/nodes
[2017-03-14T00:06:50-04:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge... [2017-03-14T00:06:50-04:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.10.4 *** [2017-03-14T00:06:50-04:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 28634 [2017-03-14T00:06:50-04:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["opsworks_custom_cookbooks::load", "opsworks_custom_cookbooks::execute"] from JSON [2017-03-14T00:06:50-04:00] WARN: Run List override has been provided. [2017-03-14T00:06:50-04:00] WARN: Original Run List: [recipe[opsworks_custom_cookbooks::load], recipe[opsworks_custom_cookbooks::execute]]
```

Is there any way possible? I am testing this from a Jenkins and want to capture the chef-log.

Comment: You'll have to play with `aws opswork describe-deployment` [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/opsworks/describe-deployments.html) and then `aws opsworks describe-commands` [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/opsworks/describe-commands.html) to retrieve the `LogUrl`, get the file from s3 and print it within Jenkins.

Comment: Side note, this is unrelated to chef, just aws way of doing things, the fact it uses chef under the hood is not really relevant.

Comment: It's also unrelated to Jenkins; I'll remove the tags.

Comment: Sure ! describe-deployment works the trick. I am able to retrive logurl.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Tensibai. `aws opswork describe-deployment` [Link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/opsworks/describe-deployments.html) will give you the required help. For eg-

```
aws opsworks describe-commands --deployment-id axxxxxxxxx-3xxxxxxx -4xxx-8xxxxx-9xxxxxxx
```

This will give you the result. where you can featch the result from linked s3 location.